# Verification of attempt related to a question on Liouville's theorem (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to prove or disprove: There exists an entire (analytic on whole of the complex plane) function $F$ such that $F(0) = 0$; $F(1)=i$; $F(z) \to0$ as $z$ approaches $\infty$.

My attempt: Since $F(z)\to 0$ as $z$ approaches $\infty$, I can say that there exists a $\delta > 0$ (depending on $\epsilon$), for each $\epsilon > 0$, such that if $\lvert z\rvert >\delta$, then $\lvert F(z)\rvert < \epsilon$.

Choosing epsilon to be $M > 0$, then corresponding to it I have a $\delta = R > 0$, such that for all $\lvert z\rvert\ge R$, I have $\lvert F(z)\rvert \lt M$.   (a)

Now if I consider a disk $D(0;R)$, then clearly since $F$ is entire (hence continuous), it will attain maximum value on the compact set $\lvert z\rvert \le R$.
Suppose, $\lvert F(z)\rvert \le N$, for a positive $N$. (#)

Now if $K= \max \{N,M\}$ then by (a) and (#)
$\lvert F(z)\rvert\le K$ for all $z$ in the complex plane. Hence by Liouville's theorem $F(z)$ is constant.

So the existence of an entire $F$ as demanded in this question is impossible.

Is my attempt alright? Did I make any mistake? Please let me know. I'll appreciate if someone helps me know.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct, but you should learn to write down proofs more clearly. This could look like this:

Since $f(z) \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$, there is a real number $M$ so that $|f(z)| < 1$ for all $z$ with $|z| > M$.
Set $K = \sup \limits_{|z| \le M} |f(z)|$. Since $\{z \mid |z| \le M\}$ is a compact set and $|f|$ is a continuous function, the value of $K$ is finite. This implies $|f(z)| \le \max\{1, K\}$ for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$, so $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{C}$. By Liouville's theorem $f$ is constant, but a constant function $f$ can't satisfy $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = i$ at the same time. Therefore no function with the desired properties exists.

Comment: f(z) approaches to 0 as z tends to infinity.But you hav written f(z) tends to infinity as z tends to infinity.

Comment: Actually I am new to this site so have some problem typing maths' symbols properly.And ,thank you very much to answer my question.

Comment: You are right, I've fixed the mistake. The problem wasn't necessarily the missing [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in your post, but the convoluted structure of your proof.

Comment: Ok,I'll improve it.Well, isn't the function f(z)= -z e^{i(-pi/2)z} exception to my proof?

Comment: No, this function doesn't approach $0$ as $z \to \infty$.

Comment: Ok, many many thanks again!

Comment: Would you please answer my one more question still unanswered? It is about limsup.

Answer (score 0):

since,$f(z) \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$. So,$z=\infty$ is a removable singularity of f(z).

then,f(z) is analytic in $\Bbb C_\infty\Rightarrow$ f is constant and hence the function cannot be non constant(as it is given $f(0)=0,f(1)=i$)